# set rhapsody DiffMerge as svn merge-tool

Tags: linux, svn, merge, rhapsody, diffmerge

I'm trying to set rhapsody DiffMerge as merge tool in SVN.

in I've set .subversion/config:

```
[helpers]
    merge-tool-cmd = /opt/rhapsody/i386/7.5.2.1/DiffMerge "$2" "$3" "$1"
```

in Rhapsody/DiffMerge i've set:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
DIFFMERGE_PATH=/opt/rhapsody/i386/7.5.2.1
DIFFMERGE_EXEC=${DIFFMERGE_PATH}/diffmerge.exe                                                                                   
${DIFFMERGE_EXEC} -xmerge "$2" "$3" -base "$1" -mergeReport mergeReport.logs
```

using DiffMerge IBM help:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rhaphlp/v7r6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rhp.diffmerge.doc%2Ftopics%2Frhp_t_col_specifying_diffmerge_cmdline_syn.html

---

When the conflict appears:

```
Select: (p) postpone,
        (mf) mine-full, (tf) theirs-full,
        (s) show all options: l
Invalid option.
```

---

Does anybody have this problem?

BR Adam

Answer (score 0):

Solved,
I've changed svn version to newest (1.8.8)
and set
merge-tool-cmd = DiffMerge

That's all.

BR Adam